# Iterating through DataTable very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, datatable

I have minimal experience with webforms / windowsforms. I started by 1st job as a developer last year with MVC web development and that is all I've done since.

My father recently asked me to create a simple application, for which I decided to try Windows Forms. What the application does is it uses OLEDB to read a excel sheet file into a `DataTable` and display's it on a `DataGridView`:

[image]

[image]

When this is done, each column is matched to a set of predefined tags and then written to a txt file in the following format:

```
@tag    (column value)
```

The excel file I have as an example to work with has some 18k rows. Reading the file with OLEDB and binding it to the `DataGridView` is pretty much instant (1/2 to 2 seconds). When I match the columns with the appropriate tags and generate the required output, however, it takes very very long (5 minutes). Considering that the `DataTable` is in memory at this stage, this feels erroneous. I'm not sure whether I might be iterating through the `DataTable` in and extremely inefficiant way.

Below is the code that iterates through the `DataTable` to create the output:

```
private void GenerateOutputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OutputDisplayRichText.Clear();
    output = string.Empty;

    string selectedT = TComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
           selectCDocdate = CDocdateComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
           selectedCSubject = CSubjectCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
           selectedTiff = TiffComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    foreach (DataRow row in excelSheet.Rows)
    {
        if (TToken.Checked)
        {
            /*..removed code..*/
            output += "@T\t\t" + tempOutput + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        if (CDocdateToken.Checked)
        {
            string rowValue = row[selectCDocdate].ToString();
            string tempOutput = "@C Docdate\t\t" + rowValue + Environment.NewLine;
            output += tempOutput;
        }
        if (CSubjectToken.Checked)
        {
            string rowValue = row[selectedCSubject].ToString();
            string tempOutput = "@C Subject\t\t" + rowValue + Environment.NewLine;
            output += tempOutput;
        }
        if (DToken.Checked)
        {
            string rowValue = DTextBox.Text;
            string tempOutput = "@D \t\t" + rowValue + Environment.NewLine;
            output += tempOutput;
        }
        if (TiffFiles.Checked)
        {
            /*..removed code..*/
            output = TTextBox.Text + "{" + pageFromStr2 + "-" + pageToStr2 + "}.tif";
        }

        output += Environment.NewLine;
    }

    OutputDisplayTextBox.Text = output;
}
```

Comment: your problem might have to do with appending all your data into a single string, which is immutable. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, which means that they cannot be changed in memory. You are appending what seems to be a great deal of information into a string variable - this creates many duplicates of the string in memory, using up more and more memory and slowing your application down.

Use the `StringBuilder` class instead - this is mutable. Example:

```
Stringbuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("text"); // adds a new line to the StringBuilder
```

When you need to output the text, call `.ToString()` on the StringBuilder instance.

Comment: Hey, StringBuilder seems to not be disposable.

Answer (score 2):

`string` in .net are immutable, so, everytime you concat two strings/values using the `+` operator, you create a new string and keep other for .net remove it from memory. To avoid this problem, you could use a `StringBuilder` instance, for sample:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in excelSheet.Rows)
{
    if (TToken.Checked)
        b.AppendLine(string.Format("@T\t\t{0}", tempOutput));

    if (CDocdateToken.Checked)
        b.AppendLine(string.Format("@C Docdate\t\t{0}", row[selectCDocdate].ToString()));

    if (CSubjectToken.Checked)
        b.AppendLine(string.Format("@C Subject\t\t{0}", row[selectedCSubject].ToString())); 

    if (DToken.Checked)
        b.AppendLine(string.Format("@D \t\t{0}", DTextBox.Text));   

    if (TiffFiles.Checked)
        b.Append(TTextBox.Text + "{" + pageFromStr2 + "-" + pageToStr2 + "}.tif");

    b.AppendLine();
}

// generate everything in a single string.
output = b.ToString();
```

Adjust it for your code, because we don't have details of it.